# Access outside the main Bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, nsbundle

I want a functionality in which my application can access resources outside its own bundle, for example: there are bunch of '3d Models' which are kept somewhere in iPhone memory (not in applications bundle), in runtime I want to load it and show it in my application,

1. Application launches.
2. User may select some model, say a dolphin.
3. Application accesses that model (which is not in the applications bundle but outside somewhere in iPhone), loads it.
4. Application displays the model.

Is it possible?
Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: **I don't think it is possible without any server**

Comment: He can use sandbox of his application. I do not think it is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **sandbox** of your application for this purpose. Read [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Puneet!
I suspect it will increase the total memory of application if I load all of the resources in the sandbox, am I right ?

Comment: No it wont. Sandbox is different from applications main bundle. It is like using a virtual space. You can save anything in the sandbox. When it will be loaded into the application then only the memory of the object will be counted. For example see How Gallery app in iOS works. It saves all the images on to the sandbox and then pick each image when user clicks on it. The thing to decide is how you are going to put those objects on to the sandbox.

Comment: I mean will it increase the '.ipa' size ?

Comment: That will depend on how you are loading the objects into the sandbox. The preferred way is to hit the web-service the first time when user installs the application and load the objects on to the sandbox. This can be done only the first time. And your .ipa size will not increase, neither the memory footprint of the application.

Comment: If the answer helped you and you are satisfied with the reasoning you can always select it answered. That will help me with points and also the other users will be benefited in case the visit this thread.